# Not able to execute RunProgramInGuest command in VMWare Workstation

Tags: cmd, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am able to perform almost all command line operation of VMware Workstation provided.

Except command `RunProgramInGuest`
I able to open `Notepad.exe, cmd.exe` using above command.
But when I try to execute my file located on Guest desktop, this command return error message:

> Error: A program could not run on the guest operating system

Command I use:

> vmrun.exe -T ws -gu "admin" -gp "password"  RunProgramInGuest
>   "D:\VMs\VMWin7_64.vmx" -activeWindow -interactive "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProgram.exe"

I also enable to run all in administrator approval mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue starting an installed program in the Guest from Program Files folder. I fixed it by settings "Run this program as an administrator" in the Compatibility tab in details dialog for the EXE in the Guest.
Guest is a Windows 10 with auto log-on for the Administrator account. So the program is running in an Administrator Desktop session.